# Aggregating counts of different columns subsets

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with a tree structure and for each path in the tree, I want to compute the corresponding counts at each level. Here is a minimal reproducible example with two levels.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['level_1'] = np.random.choice(['1', '2', '3'], 100)
data['level_2'] = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 100)
```

I know I can get the counts on the last level by doing

```
counts = data.groupby(['level_1','level_2']).size().reset_index(name='count_2')
print(counts)

    level_1 level_2 count_2
0   1       A       10
1   1       B       12
2   1       C       8
3   2       A       10
4   2       B       10
5   2       C       10
6   3       A       17
7   3       B       12
8   3       C       11
```

What I would like to have is a dataframe with one row for each possible path in the tree with the counts at each level in that path. For the example above, it would be something like

```
    level_1 level_2 count_1 count_2
0   1       A       30      10
1   1       B       30      12
2   1       C       30      8
3   2       A       30      10
4   2       B       30      10
5   2       C       30      10
6   3       A       40      17
7   3       B       40      12
8   3       C       40      11
```

This is an example with only two levels, which is easy to solve, but I would like to have a way to get those counts for an arbitrary number of levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the `transform`

```
counts['count_1']=counts.groupby(['level_1']).count_2.transform('sum')
counts
Out[445]: 
  level_1 level_2  count_2  count_1
0       1       A        7       30
1       1       B       13       30
2       1       C       10       30
3       2       A        7       30
4       2       B        7       30
5       2       C       16       30
6       3       A        9       40
7       3       B       10       40
8       3       C       21       40
```

Comment: @AlCorreia yw happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can make do from your original data:

```
groups = data.groupby('level_1').level_2

pd.merge(groups.value_counts(),
         groups.size(),
         left_index=True,
         right_index=True)
```

which gives:

```
                 level_2_x  level_2_y
level_1 level_2                      
1       A               14         39
        B               14         39
        C               11         39
2       C               13         34
        A               12         34
        B                9         34
3       B               12         27
        C                9         27
        A                6         27
```

Comment: That is nice, but I could not make it work for some reason. What exactly is ``groups`` in your answer?

Comment: Sorry not to include the important piece :D